# How to do memory analysis of heap allocated objects in an embedded systems?

Tags: memory, embedded, heap-memory

I'm trying to analyze the memory usage of our systems. We have some singleton objects that are allocated on the heap at start-up. I would like to get the size of those objects. The information has to be there, since the debugger knows how big they are. How can I dump that info out of dwarf2 debugging information? Our compiler is WindRiver (Diab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU objdump seems to do the trick, objdump -W myfile.elf dumps the debug info in text format, and that can be searched to find the information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably add a bit of debug code that spit the result of a `sizeof` operation to the console or a log file. I don't know if there's a utility already out there that'll do what you want; there probably is, but I'm unaware of it (someone will likely chime in here).

Comment: I need to do it offline with a script, not by running the code.

Comment: Understood - glad you found a solution (I'm surprised no one else mentioned it).

Answer (score 0):

The size of an object is a compile time constant. That is what the sizeof() operator returns and how the debugger knows, but it does not include memory dynamically allocated by that object.

VxWorks has a showMem() function for monitoring heap usage. I have used it in the past to measure object footprint by writing test code to instantiate it with showMem calls before and after. I have also used it to test that all memory is returned when the destructor is called.

For more sophisticated memory analysis, port the code to Linux and use a tool such as Valgrind.